# HTML Interface for a java chatclient

Tags: java, html, applet

I have this project thats about to start. We're making a Chatclient that we want to integrate to a webapp.

We have the following requirments:
 - Java server
 - Java client

We've practically compleated the coding of both the client and server, but the thing is that we want to integrate the client applet into a webapp with all the layouting done in HTML. Basically, we need a interface in HTML but the backend in java on the browser. How do we do that?

Comment: AFAIK you can't use applets layed out by HTML. Thus you'd need to make a HTML/AJAX client in order to be able to use the webapp's layout and CSS.

Comment: Applet are native Java applications running in a sandbox, as a plug-in of the browser. The browser allows the plug-in to render whatever in its controlled area. This area is not HTML, so you are mixing technologies. If you want your Java Applet look like the rest of the HTML page, you can but it's not easy.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider rendering your HTML client code with Java Servlets os JSP.